# Python help needed cant seem to solve this

Tags: python

I'm suppose to write a code to give me the output of a value between `0` and `86400` and the current time in the 24 hour clock. However I am getting stuck when it comes to writing the formulas for the 24 hour clock and the print function. Here's the code I have written so far.

```
total_time = float('70000')
hours = int(total_time / 3600.0)
minutes = int((total_time - (hours * 3600.0)) / 60.0)
seconds = int(((total_time) - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60)))
print("Enter a value between 0 and 86400", total_time) print("The current time is",hours.minutes.seconds)
```

Comment: What exactly does *"I am getting stuck when it comes to writing the formulas"* mean?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, get the current hour, minute and seconds:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

# The current time:
hour = now.hour
minute = now.minute
second = now.second
```

Then simply output it:

```
print("Current time: {}:{}:{}".format(hour,minute,second))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are asking the user to enter a number between 0 and 86400 and then you want to translate that to `hh:mm:ss` format. But your code is not getting any input from the user, and the last line of the code has syntax errors.

To get you started, you need to fix your `print()` calls at the end. Put one statement to a line, and use commas not fullstops:

```
print("Enter a value between 0 and 86400", total_time) 
print("The current time is",hours,minutes,seconds)
```

That will give you the output:

```
Enter a value between 0 and 86400 70000.0
The current time is 19 26 40
```

Which is correct, in the sense that an offset of 70,000 seconds from 0h00 today is 19h26m40s.

If you want to get actual user input, then you need to ask for it, at the top of your program, *before* you do the calculations, in an `input()` call:

```
total_time=float(input("Enter a value between 0 and 86400: "))
```

If you want pretty formatting of the answer then do

```
print(f"The current time is {hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}")
```

None of this relates to finding the current time, which Suraj Kothari's answer addresses.